# unknown javascript cookies being added to localhost from nowhere

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've recently been working with **JavaScript** cookies, and thus have been needing to check my webpages `cookies` panel quite often.

All of it seems quite normal, except for the fact that two random cookies (with values), keep seeming to appear (after I delete, then refresh the page).

I have no idea where they're coming from, and they only seem to affect my `localhost`.

This seems pretty strange, and I have never actually interacted with the domain that is associated with the cookie.

Here's a screenshot of the *offending* cookies:

[image: Screenshot of cookies]

All help would be appreciated in telling me how these might be getting here, and how I can remove them **permanently**.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I tried disabling all of my extensions and then removing the cookies, however, they still appear after hard refreshing the page.

Comment: Did you check all browsers? Perhaps you have some third-party plugin installed.

Comment: @loelsonk It doesn't appear to happen in Firefox or Edge, so I'm assuming it does have something to do with a plugin or extension. But the only things I have installed are **uBlock Origin** (an Adblocker), an Eyedropper tool, and a ruler. What's strange is that it **only** happens on localhost.

Comment: @loelsonk I disabled all of my extensions and then removed the Cookies. However, they keep coming back :/

Comment: Did you try running `chrome` in safe mode?

Comment: @loelsonk gonna be honest with you and say I didn't even know chrome had a safe mode lol. How would I do that? :)

Comment: I am not sure but `--disable-extensions` flag should work. Google it.

Comment: @loelsonk doesn't do anything unfortunately :/ still there

Comment: Do you have some kind of `oAuth2` service running, some external js libs? These may add cookies.

Comment: @loelsonk nah I don't. Even then, `comicsforsinners.com`? :/ strange cookie domain to add

Comment: Reinstall Chrome or try with `Chrome Canary`. Could be the fastest way to solve this problem.